# HTML being removed when rewriting field in Views

Tags: views, blocks

I have completely stripped all my views/blocks down so they only produce exactly what I put into them..but I created a view and rewrote the fields and this part of my code will not print exactly as it is here:

```
<div style="background-image: url('sites/all/themes/my-theme/images/my-image.jpg');" class="slides-fullscreen-img"></div>
```

Instead, when the block is rendered I get:

```
<div class="slides-fullscreen-img"></div>
```

So it strips away come of my code. Does anyone know how I can get round this problem?

Comment: Have you tried PHP code?

Answer (score 0):

Adding a class and then the style to your stylesheet is the normal practise.  Quick fix

.slides-full-screen-image {
Background-image:  url....

}

If you have more calls to that class where you don't want the image then you should add an additional class name.

Comment: Thanks but that means I cannot use the backend of Drupal to upload images, as the file names needs to be in the CSS. In this case it's a parallax website.

Comment: Does that mean you set up an empty class for .slides-full-screen-image and edit in firebug ; you can't get the image to display even if you use the full image url ? Inc Http://wwww.you website etc